# Interrupt kernel process or another interrupt

Tags: linux, mips, interrupt, interrupt-handling

How ISR knows that it interrupts process in kernel mode or another interrupt (which enables further interrupts) - of course in kernel mode too.

If this question is very wide, please aim to Linux on MIPS.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: How do you know that the ISR knows that?